# Sudoers to remove password from specific commands

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I'm having a bit of trouble with sudoers syntax. Long story short, I'm struggling with my graphics card and I recently found out that I can turn it on and off with a simple command (previously it was always off, which is good 90% of the times, but sometimes I'd like to use its extra power sometimes). My idea is to use these two commands in various script to turn on the GC, execute a command that uses the GC and then turn it off, something like this:

```
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<ON
optirun [command]
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
```

Problem is, these script are very rarely executed in a shell, they are mostly executed by double-clicking on the .sh file. So I looked into how to avoid password for specific `sudo` commands and found out about `sudoers`.

I executed `visudo` and added a line at the end of the file:

```
grb ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF, tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<ON
```

but as soon as I close the editor, `visudo` says there is a syntax error, but nothing more. The syntax error is raised even if I add only one command:

```
grb ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
```

This line was added as the last and it's the first time that I edit the `sudoers` file.

If it's useful, I'm using Ubuntu MATE 18.04. I suspect the answer is really simple, but I can't find any documentation specific enough for my case. I want to stress that I need to limit the possible inputs to `/proc/acpi/bbswitch` to ON and OFF, I don't know what happens if I write something different and judging from the amount of troubles my GC gave me it will probably be something bad. I have to know that if I'm asked a password or the program doesn't start, I have to check that the switch commands are written correctly.

Comment: Note that the redirection is not part of the command.

Comment: Maybe the practical solution would be to create a script (perhaps using a `case` statement, that does nothing for cases other than `ON` and `OFF`) and make *that* executable without a password?

Comment: @Kusalananda That's what I suspected. Is there a way to make it part of the command?

Comment: I'd use `gksudo` instead of sudo, so a windows, when used, will prompt a graphic dialog to enter the password

Comment: @steeldriver That may be a really good and easy idea. If there are no direct solutions, you should post your answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @DDS I'd rather not write a password at all, sorry.

Comment: What I meant was, don't include the redirection with `<<<` in the `sudoers` file.

Comment: @Kusalananda I could do it this way, but I'd like to limit the possible inputs to only ON and OFF, otherwise a password should be required.

Comment: @GRB Then you wound _need_ to write a script that takes command line options that makes it turn the thing on or off. Alternatively, one script for turning on and another for turning off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A redirection is not part of the actual command. It's just an instruction to the shell to arrange the plumbing for standard input and output in certain ways *before* actually running the command.

Therefore, it makes no sense to include the `<<<` "here-string" redirection in the command in the `sudoers` file.

Instead, since you'd like to restrict the use to *only* allowing the strings `ON` or `OFF` to be written to `/proc/acpi/bbswitch`, you could make a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
    ON)  ;;  # nothing
    OFF) ;;  # nothing here either
    *) printf 'Usage: %s ON|OFF\n' "$0" >&2
       exit 1
esac

printf '%s\n' "$1" >/proc/acpi/bbswitch
```

You would then put this in a directory where the required users could access it, but not modify it, and allow them to use it with the `ON` or `OFF` command line argument, e.g.

```
grb ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /some/path/script.sh ON, /some/path/script.sh OFF
```

(or something similar)